# Sonar and Jenkins- Integration tests

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, integration-testing, sonarqube

I have a problem of comprehension.

Unit tests are coded by developers in order to test a class (Java).
Integration tests are aimed to know if the different classes work together.

My problem is: 
Based on continuous integration: I have Subversion (SVN) linked to Jenkins, and Sonar linked to Jenkins.

How are the integration tests created? Who does them? Are these tests already available in Sonar, or developers have to code them? Sonar launches integration tests thanks to Jenkins? How does it work...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration tests are also coded by developers, to test multiple classes at one time, conceptually a "module", whatever that means in your world.

In my world, unit tests are tests that exercise one class, and have no dependencies externally.  We allow file system access for mock data and logging, but that's all.

If a test exercises an actual database, or a running executable somewhere (e.g. web service) it is an integration test.  We write them with junit, same as a unit test.

We find it works best for us to have separate Jenkins jobs linked in a pipeline to build, execute unit tests, execute integration tests, and load Sonar.  While SonarQube is able to run tests for you, we prefer the separation which allows us to manually execute either set of tests via Jenkins without updating Sonar at the same time.